# CSS Changing Background Color

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade

Essentially I'd like to fade the background from black to gray, I've accomplished this with the following code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #000000; }
  50%  { background-color: #1E1E1E; }
  100% { background-color: #3C3C3C; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #000000; }
  50%  { background-color: #1E1E1E; }
  100% { background-color: #3C3C3C; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #000000; }
  50%  { background-color: #1E1E1E; }
  100% { background-color: #3C3C3C; }
}

@keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #000000; }
  50%  { background-color: #1E1E1E; }
  100% { background-color: #3C3C3C; }
}

body {
    background-image:none !important;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
       -moz-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
         -o-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
            animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out;

    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Once the transition has been processed, the color is set to white which isn't ideal, I'd like it to be set to gray. A simple

```
background-color: 000000;
```

tag in the body wont do it as its overridden by the fade, how can I set a timeout to convert it to gray once the fade has completed?

The gray hex I'm using is `3C3C3C` (`0x3C3C3C`) (`#3C3C3C`)

Comment: Adding `background-color:#3C3C3C;` to the `body` seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tb3xf7z9/ (tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari)

Comment: Weird, Thanks anyway ^-^

Comment: @APAD1, I think you should post it as an answer, and GenaratedPixelz aside from the question try to set the time to `3s`. instead